# div fill rest of the screen height

Tags: html, css

I'm using a navbar with smooth scrolling to get to my 3 divs. I want each div to fill the entire screen and it would auto adjust. I'm using this code, but I just want to make sure if there is a better way to do this. If not, my one issue with this is that once I get to the 2nd div my navbar disappears despite the sticky top.

```css
I'm using a navbar with smooth scrolling to get to my 3 divs. I want each div to fill the entire screen and it would auto adjust. I'm using this code,
but I just want to make sure if there is a better way to do this. If not,
my one issue with this is that once I get to the 2nd div my navbar disappears despite the sticky top. html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll@14.0.0/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Scripts -->

  <!-- Links -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Links -->

  <!-- Local -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Local -->

  <!-- Scroll -->
  <script>
    var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');
  </script>
  <!-- Scroll -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <!-- Navigation Start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link active">Title</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#quote" class="nav-link">Request a Quote</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navigation End -->

  <div id="home" class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 100px;">

    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Form Start -->
    <div id="quote" class="container-fluid bg-dark" style="padding-top: 70px;padding-bottom: 70px;">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Featured
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Featured
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Featured
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- Form End -->
    <div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-info" style="padding-top: 70px;padding-bottom: 70px;">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
        of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
        loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious
        physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: show your html also in snippet

Comment: @לבנימלכה Added!

Comment: A snippet combines HTML and CSS (and JS, if desired). Your snippet only contains CSS (which won't produce any visible result), and after that there is separate HTML code. Move the HTML code into the snippet.

Comment: forget it, I just did it for you...

Comment: @Johannes Sorry, I'm still trying to get the hang of stackoverflows features. Thank you for doing that

Comment: So it seems like on the snipper the navbar doesn't go away, but on my desktop screen it like hides itself.